# Servo motor driver input ratings

Tags: motor, servo

A [servomotor drive](http://www.ni.com/pdf/manuals/AKD_Install.pdf) input can be supplied with either three-phase or single-phase.

Photo of the driver nameplate:

[image]

Does that mean in full/nominal load if this drive is supplied single-phase, it will draw 9.9 A RMS current through line? This makes sense to me because I=P/V so I = 2.38 kVA/240 is around 9.9 A. I might have ignored the power factor (?).

But FL current is written as 9.9/4.6 A. Does that mean in case of three-phase power input the total current drawn will be 4.6 A? How can we calculate 4.6 A from 2.38 kVA?

Motor nameplate:

[image]

Comment: Power of three phase is \$P=\sqrt{3}\cdot V\cdot I\$

Comment: But in that case I calculate the current I = P/(sqrt(3)*V) = 5.72 A  in nameplate it says 4.6 A (?)

Comment: Well, also the output power 240V @ 6A would give 2.5kW which is higher than input power. You'd better ask the manufacturer what is the meaing of the data.

Comment: You probably need to find a more detailed specification in the instruction manual or other publication. Nameplate information tends to be based on worst case or conditions set by safety standards. That sometimes leads to inconsistencies. The 2.38 kVA may be the short-term maximum under worst case conditions while the full-load current is continuous current under typical conditions.

Comment: The output kVA can be higher than the input kVA because there is inherent power factor compensation in the controller.

Comment: What probably is going on is that regardless of whether you feed it 240V single phase or 240V 3 phase, it is only pulling current from 2 of the 3 phases, that's why the current is basically the same either way.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Now look carefully. Continuous output power @ rated input current:
It says for 3 x 240 VAC input voltage, that will have 4.6 A rated input current, the output power is 1250 W.

Let's calculate the output voltage:
$$V=\dfrac{1250\ \mathrm{V\!A}}{\sqrt{3}\cdot 6\ \mathrm{A}}= 120\ \mathrm{V}$$

It makes sense now: the input apparent power is 2 kVA and the output power is 1.3 kVA. But this driver can't provide 240 VAC @ 6A output voltage. You'd need to contact the manufacturer for further explanations.

Anyway, what is the connected motor?

[image]

[image]

I'll explain later...

Comment: Here is the motor's nameplate https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvvAh.jpg

Comment: Hello again, how did it go with the answer, you were elaborating. thanks

Comment: @cmd The manuals and datasheets have typos. Your drive can supply 2000W output, not 1250VA as declared in first datasheet. The motor will suit very good, you can install fuses according to the manual. What really concerns you? I can edit the answer with choosen motor - output voltage, output current on S1 duty.